# ¿Como formatear fecha simple en vuejs2 con un filtro?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Recibo un objeto json de consultas a una api, pero el formato que obtengo es el siguiente

`2018-07-03T05:47:00.000Z`

aunque necesito simplemente mostrar esto

```
2018-07-03
```

Answer (score 1):

Si al igual que yo, tienen un caso similar la solución mas sencilla es registrar un filtro con un split en nuestro archivo main.js que en este caso seria así

```
  Vue.filter('formatDate', function(value) {
  if (value) {
    return value.split("T")[0];
  }
});
```

al momento de renderizar simplemente utilizamos nuestro nuevo y flamante filtro

```
{{value.date  | formatDate }}
```

espero les sea de utilidad si llegan a necesitarlo.